# Wordpress query for getting user generated content not work

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm using WordPress for developing a website. I create user-generated content page so users can visit that page and create some note (note can only be seen by the person who made the notes)

steps I took,

1. create a new page name **My Note** (slug- my-notes)
2. create file and name it **page-my-note.php** in theme file
3. create post type name **note**
4. create some Note
5. wrote a **query** in page-my-note.php file
6. wrote **while loop** for getting title and content

but code is not working, it output a blank page.
Please help me to solve this issue. (code is below)
Thankyou.

```
<ul class="min-list link-list" id="my-notes">
    <?php 
      $userNotes = new WP_Query(array(
        'post_type' => 'note',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'author' => get_current_user_id()
      ));
      
      while($userNotes->have_posts()) {
        $userNotes->the_post(); ?>

        <li>
          <input class="note-title-field" value="<?php echo esc_attr(get_the_title()); ?>">
          <textarea class="note-body-field"><?php echo esc_attr(get_the_content()); ?></textarea>
        </li>

      <?php }
    ?>
  </ul>
```